# Using NLog with WPF richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, nlog

I have an application which has several tabs. I am trying to add logging with NLog where the output is directed to a richtextbox.

My main form is an instance of a class `MyNamespace.MainWindow` and its name is `MainWindow1`. It has a tab and in that tab I have a `RichTextBox` called `rtbLogBox`

I have imported `WpfRichTextBox` extension from `NuGet`and place this piece of code in the MainWindow class's loaded event

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(logger == null) logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        WpfRichTextBoxTarget rtbTarget = new WpfRichTextBoxTarget
        {
            Name = "rtbLog",
            ControlName = "rtbLogBox",
            FormName = "MainWindow"
        };

        LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(rtbTarget);


        LogManager.Configuration.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, rtbTarget.Name);

        logger.Info("This");
    }
```

The problem is that this does not produce any outputs in the RichTextBox control.

I have an output to a file in addition to this and that target gets the log when I run the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the logger is created before you are changing the LogManager's configuration, you need to notify the logger of the change.

Calling `LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers()` should do the trick.

[Documentation is here.](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_ReconfigExistingLoggers.htm)

Comment: Thank you but this didn't fix my problem.

Comment: This actually did work but the output was white so I couldn't see. Is there a way to put it in the NLog.Config?

Comment: It probably should, although I'm not exactly sure since I can't test it right now. Try setting it up similar to the WinForms one see documentation [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Windows.Forms/wiki/RichTextBoxTarget). The interface seems to be similar, just specify the xsi:type as WpfRichTextBox and fill out the same properties as you did in your example. Since it will be loaded before the logger is created calling the Reconfig method shouldn't be necessary. If you have any trouble it would be worth posting a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use my `wpf control`. (https://github.com/dojo90/NLogViewer). There is also a nuget package available.

[image]

Comment: You're a life saver, thank you.